# How do I update an sql foreach input box

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update mysql affiliate IDs, I have one update button.

I have something like this.

```
foreach($_POST['affid'] as $index_id => $value) {
   $key = 'affId_'.$value; 

   $dosql = ("UPDATE dlbprog SET affId='$key' affId =".$value);

   $doupdate = mysql_query($dosql);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appretiated

I don't quite know how to do this

dlbprog is the database name, affId is the database field, affid is the inputbox name.

There are several inputbox's and only one submit button.

Comment: Well, you definitely need a `WHERE` clause in your statement: `$dosql = ("UPDATE dlbprog SET affId='$key' WHERE affId =".$value);`

Comment: Unless you do some basic [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you are going to get in serious trouble. Is there any reason to not use a simple [ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library) to help with simple queries like this? Learning SQL from the ground up is not easy. Having a framework to help get you started is essential.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? It's unclear to me. What is `$key`? You should stop using `mysql_` functions as they are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). Look into `PDO` or `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: @SetSailMedia I added where affId = affId and ownerId=$uid

Comment: @njk I am trying to update multiple affids for however many there are, using one submit button. idk what $key is I could rewrite the whole thing, been trying to splice some things together to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

foreach($_POST['affid'] as $id) {

   $id = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($id));
   $aff_id = 'affId_'.$id;

   $sql = "UPDATE dlbprog SET affId='$aff_id' WHERE affId='$aff_id'";

   mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

This works with checkbox or multiple select form tags. But if you are just dealing with just one affiliate ID, no need for loop. ALso check your name attribute if it mismatch with $_POST['affid']

Make sure it is a checkbox and its name attribute is name="affid[]" not name="affid"

Comment: Invalid arguments supplied foreach. There are multiple affiliate IDs in different boxes (say for instance I want to update 3 programs)

Comment: <table border="1" width="90%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><tr><td align="left" colspan="2">'.$row["description"].'
</td></tr><tr><td align="left" width="55%">To Sign Up <a href="'.$row["progUrl"].'" target="_blank">Click Here</a><br /><input type="checkbox" name="blocked" value="1"  />&nbsp;Block this program</td><td align="left" width="45%">Your Affiliate Id: &nbsp; 
<input type="text" class="input" size="30" name="affid" value="'.$row["affId"].'"></td></tr></table><p>&nbsp;</p>

Comment: If that is the problem $_POST['affid'] is not an array but a string

Comment: affid is a string, it is the content from the textbox, class=input type=text

Comment: THere may only be one, or there could be 200, depends on as many programs that are generated, or rather, viewed

Comment: Yes $_POST['affid'] is intended to be the content or value of the text box that is supposed to Update the database with. For example if I change value from 829 to 998

Comment: If `$id` is a string, you're still going to have a SQL injection vulnerability... it'd be safer just to slap an `(int)` in front of it and forget `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Also why affId='$aff_id' affId =$id ?

Comment: There is no WHERE clause that is why your query doent which record you want to update.

Comment: What should the WHERE clause be? I added WHERE ownerId=$uid so that it only replaces the ids that member owns

Comment: Can you post your mysql schema for the table?

Comment: If this is what you mean: id (int11 Auto Increment) programId(int11) description(varchar255) progUrl(varchar255) category(char1) affId(varchar50) ownerId(int25) dlbCat(varchar50)

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE dlbprog SET affId='$aff_id' WHERE affId='$aff_id'";

Comment: It says "UPDATE dlbprog SET affId=111 WHERE affId=111UPDATE dlbprog SET affId=333 WHERE affId=333" (That is the output) whereas it should say "UPDATE dlbprog SET affId=111 WHERE affId=323UPDATE dlbprog SET affId=333 WHERE affId=424 "

Comment: In other words it is not replacing the old data. Or rather not getting the old affIds. Also aff_id is not needed, I don't need the affId= at the beginning, just the id number

Comment: foreach($_POST['affid'] as $id) {
    
              $id =         @mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($id));
    
              $sql =     "UPDATE dlbprog SET affId=".$id." WHERE affId=".$oldid;
       
       echo $sql;

          //@mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      }

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: oldid in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdimi\m_dlbuilder.php on line 56
UPDATE dlbprog SET affId=111 WHERE affId=
Notice: Undefined variable: oldid in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdimi\m_dlbuilder.php on line 56
UPDATE dlbprog SET affId=222 WHERE affId=

Comment: first one should read affId=323 and the second one should read affId=424 for the WHERE claus (the old affIds, so it knows what to replace)

Comment: Anybody know how I can get the old value, so that I may UPDATE WHERE affId = oldvalue? The thing that stumbles me is how it is in a foreach statement.